# How do i get all ArrayList elements that are >n

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop, arraylist

Is there any other way to find all `ArrayList<Long>` elements that are bigger than `n`. Now  I'm using default for-loop

```
 List<Long>nex= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            if(Long.valueOf(result.get(i))>n){
                nex.add(Long.valueOf(result.get(i)));
            }
        }
```

It works just fine, but it is too slow as my result.size is usually >20k ( I'm trying to solve a permutation task)  so I'm looking for some ways to refactor some parts of my code.

Thank you in advance.
Peace and love!

Comment: If you are calling this method many times, sort once and do a binary search. You haven't shown us the other parts of the code to understand the full context

Comment: What is the type of `result`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to use a Collection that implement SortedSet, thus each add will be sorted and you could then break your loop as soon as you met your limit.

Example :

```
import java.util.*;

public class AnonymousTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedSet<Integer> integers = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> (Integer) s).reversed());
        integers.add(2);
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(9);
        integers.add(4);
        integers.stream().takeWhile(i -> i > 3).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
        integers.add(3);
        integers.add(6);
        integers.stream().takeWhile(i -> i > 3).forEach(System.out::print);
    }
}
```

output

```
94
964
```

Another way to optimize it would be to store the index where the integers would be greater than `n` and directly return element from there

Comment: To create a set with reverse order, just use `new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())`. On the other hand, you don’t need reverse order if you use the built-in facilities to get the desired elements, e.g. `SortedSet<Integer> integers = new TreeSet<>(); Collections.addAll(integers, 2, 1, 9, 4); System.out.println(integers.tailSet(4)); Collections.addAll(integers, 3, 6); System.out.println(integers.tailSet(4));`